# Run applet java in html

Tags: java, image, applet, dicom

I have an applet java displaying images from folder  ,i cant run this applet using html i have this error :

[image]

Comment: please don't post screenshots of error messages. Just add the text of the error message to your question.

Comment: also, that message already has some indication for what's going wrong. Have you considered that? What about that file and its permissions?

Comment: How is that question related to DICOM?

Comment: the applet run correctly with java applet viewer but when i use it in html it doesn't work  it give me access denied java.io.FilePermission  "the folder" "read"

Comment: the applet run dicom images

Comment: Hint: applets are dead technology. Only bother learning about this dinosaur-technology if you are working in/for a company that still uses them. Anything else is a waste of your time.

Comment: but i can't read dicom image without java applet can you give me an ather way to read it

Comment: @Abdelilahsidiali There are a few JavaScript based DICOM readers/viewers out there.  Here's one (I am involved with this project): [Papaya](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya). Here's another: [Cornerstone](https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because your applet is trying to read a file from a directory in the local system where it is getting downloaded.  This is a standard security feature. This of this way, you go to a website which downloads an applet and read a file or executes an .exe in your local system. Naturally this should not be allowed for an applet / javascript or code served from a server.

You need to create a signed applet. Please go through the following link to accomplish your need :

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm